# Next with Revolution R's foreach package?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I've looked through much of the documentation and done a fair amount of Googling, but can't find an answer to the following question: Is there a way to induce 'next-like' functionality in a parallel `foreach` loop using the `foreach` package?

Specifically, I'd like to do something like (this doesn't work with `next` but does without):

```
foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = "c") %dopar% {
    n <- i + floor(runif(1, 0, 9))
    if (n %% 3) {next}
    n
}
```

I realize I can nest my brackets, but if I want to have a few next conditions over a long loop this very quickly becomes a syntax nightmare.

Is there an easy workaround here (either next-like functionality or a different way of approaching the problem)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could put your code in a function and call `return`.  It's not clear from your example what you want it to do when `n %% 3` so I'll return `NA`.

```
funi <- function(i) {
  n <- i + floor(runif(1, 0, 9))
  if (n %% 3) return(NA)
  n
}
foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = "c") %dopar% { funi(i) }
```

Comment: Perfect -- thanks -- didn't think to use `return` and a function. And yes, modulus 3 is a highly arbitrary example, sorry.

Comment: The example was fine and easily showed your situation.  What I meant was that `next` has a different behavior than `return`; next means that that instance of the loop doesn't do anything at all, which is impossible when using `foreach`; each instance has to return *something*; so you'll want to make sure that you're handling whatever you choose to return appropriately.

Answer (score 15):

Although it seems strange, you can use a `return` in the body of a foreach loop, without the need for an auxiliary function (as demonstrated by @Aaron):

```
r <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine='c') %dopar% {
  n <- i + floor(runif(1, 0, 9))
  if (n %% 3) return(NULL)
  n
}
```

A `NULL` is returned in this example since it is filtered out by the `c` function, which can be useful.

Also, although it doesn't work well for your example, the `when` function can take the place of `next` at times, and is useful for preventing the computation from taking place at all:

```
r <- foreach(i=1:5, .combine='c') %:%
         foreach(j=1:5, .combine='c') %:%
             when (i != j) %dopar% {
                 10 * i + j
             }
```

The inner expression is only evaluated 20 times, not 25.  This is particularly useful with nested foreach loops, since `when` has access to all of the upstream iterator values.

---

*Update*

If you want to filter out `NULL`s when returning the results in a list, you need to write your own combine function. Here's a complete example that demonstrates a combine function that works like the default combine function but includes a filtering mechanism:

```
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

filteredlist <- function(a, ...) {
  values <- list(...)
  c(a, values[! sapply(values, is.null)])
}

r <- foreach(i=1:200, .combine='filteredlist', .init=list(),
             .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  # filter out odd values of i
  if (i %% 2) return(NULL)
  i
}
```

Note that this code works correctly when there are more than 100 task results (100 is the default value of the `.maxcombine` option).

Comment: +1. This only works for `.combine='c'`. If one needs it for the default list output, you have to [remove the NULL list elements](http://economics.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/remove-null-elements-from-a-list-in-r/) afterwards by `r[!sapply(r, is.null)]`.

Comment: @TMS I added an example that filters out NULL's when you want to return the results in a list. Although you could do it afterwards, it can be more efficient to do this in the combine function, particularly when done on-the-fly with the `doSNOW` and `doMPI` backends.

Answer (score 0):

A note to the previous answers, you should use `return()` or `return(NULL)` (like in answer 2) rather then `return(NA)` (answer 1). Otherwise you will get errors like below

```
>     error calling combine function:
>     <simpleError in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol): Item 4 has 1 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 16 columns. To fill
> missing columns use fill=TRUE.>
```