# How to use statements "next"/"break" with foreach

Tags: r, if-statement, parallel.foreach

When I use a `for` loop, I typically have `if` constructs with `next` and `break` statements. Solving some problems and logical steps just requires that. However I am unable to use `next`, `break` statements in the `foreach` package. How can I use these statements inside of `foreach` looping structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Next with Revolution R's foreach package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707467/next-with-revolution-rs-foreach-package)

Answer (score 0):

The general idea when using the `foreach` package is that every iteration can be performed in parallel; so if you had `N` iteration and `N` CPUs you would get (ignoring thread communication) perfect speed-up.

So instead of using `break`, return an `NA` or `0` as early as possible. For example

```
library("foreach")
f = function(i) if(i < 3) sqrt(i) else NA
foreach(i=1:5) %do% f(i)
```

Now you could argue that you have wasted resources for `i=4` and `i=5`, but this amounts to nano/microseconds and your total computation is measured in seconds/minutes.